# Specifying auto column width in jQuery dataTables

Tags: jquery, width, datatables

I'm using Datatables. Columns have auto width, I want to make their width smaller. I tried some things, but it doesn't change. My table is:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "bSort": true,
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                    "csv",
                    {
                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                        "sButtonText": "Print PDF",
                        "mColumns": "visible"
                    },
                    "xls"
                ]
            },

        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "width": "5%"
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples

Set the first column's width to 20% with columnDefsDT:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

Set the first column's width to 20% with columnsDT:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    { "width": "20%" },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
} );
```

Comment: I tried with the second and it changes, but table doesn't look like Datatable - it disappears sorting in head of the tables and search in foot.